# Laravel Many to many store to database

Tags: php, laravel, upload, many-to-many, store

I want a system where I connect users with tasks and later I can assign tasks to different users from the amdin panel. My program doesn't work, it doesn't assign tasks to users. Later, I want to make sure that when a user logs in, they can only see their own tasks that an amdin has given them. Please help me what is the problem?!

Create user_task

```
Schema::create('user_task', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('task_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        
        });
```

Create users

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('avatar')->default('default.jpg');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Create tasks

```
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('alkalmazott');
            $table->string('projekt')->default('-');
            $table->string('feladat');
            $table->date('hatarido');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Task model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'alkalmazott', 'projekt' , 'feladat', 'hatarido'
    ];
   
    public function projects(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Project');
    }
    public function users()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_tasks');
    }
 
}
```

User model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Tasks;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    //public function setPasswordAttribute($password) {
      //  $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
    //}

    public function jogoks(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Jogok');
    }
   
   
    public function tasks()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Task', 'user_tasks');
}
        /* Check if the user has a role
        * @param string $role
        * @return bool
        */
    public function hasAnyRole(string $role){
        return null !== $this->jogoks()->where('name', $role)->first();        
    }
    /* Check if the user has any given role
        * @param array $role
        * @return bool
        */
    public function hasAnyRoles(array $role){
        return null !== $this->jogoks()->whereIn('name', $role)->first();        
    }

}
```

Task controller (here i want to upload tasks)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Project;
use App\Models\Task;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TasksController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $tasks = Task::latest()->paginate(10);
    
        return view('admin.tasks.index',compact('tasks'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.tasks.create', ['users' => User::all()], ['tasks' => Task::all()]);
        
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'alkalmazott' => 'required',
            'projekt' => 'required',
            'feladat' => 'required',
            'hatarido' => 'required',
            
        ]);
        
       Task::create($request->all());
 

        return redirect()->route('admin.tasks.index')
                        ->with('success','Product created successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Task  $Task
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Task $Task)
    {
        return view('admin.tasks.show',compact('Task'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Task  $Task
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Task $Task)
    {
        return view('admin.tasks.edit',compact('Task'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Task  $Task
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Task $Task)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'alkalmazott' => 'required',
            'projekt' => 'required',
            'feladat' => 'required',
            'hatarido' => 'required',
        ]);
        
        $Task->update($request->all());
        
        return redirect()->route('admin.tasks.index')
                        ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
                    
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Task  $Task
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Task $Task)
    {
        $Task->delete();
    
        return redirect()->route('admin.tasks.index')
                        ->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

And after i run my upload form, on the phpmyadmin the task has uploaded done but in the user_task table not working. Because its not working i cant display tasks for the users. Thank you for your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attach(), detach() or sync() functions in controller.

For example:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    // ...

    $task = Task::create($request->all());
    $task->users->attach($request->users); // or you can use sync(), according to your needs and project
    // $request->users must be an array like [1,3,10,21,28] etc.
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I put this `$task->users()->sync($request->users);` sync i think it's better for me but the problem is the same... Class 'User' not found

Comment: Okay i used the sync and i found the problem on the models -> I changed the `return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_task');` to `return $this->belongsToMany(User:class, 'user_task');` And the same in the Task model... But the problem not solved. Now the store function is working but i can't see anything in my user_task table... so it's empty

Comment: It doesen't work and it doedent metter that i use sync or attach :(

Comment: May i see all your project with all your codes on github or any another platform, i wanna help you